# Sub-Form in Swift Eureka

Tags: swift, swift3, eureka-forms

I'm using Eureka Form-Framework in Swift 3 project.

I need to use MultivaluedSection, but instead of fetching a String out of a String options array (like in code below), I want to open a subform (e.g. with TextRow, NumberRow, ...) in a presented controller.

I know, that I can implement a custom presenter row, but I don't find a solution to show a "sub-form" for a custom presenter row.

Is this even possible with Eureka framework?

```
let multivaluedSection = MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Insert, .Delete],
                                                    header: rawField["name"].stringValue,
                                                    footer: "")
multivaluedSection.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
            return PushRow<String>{
                $0.title = "Tap to select ;)..at \(index)"
                $0.options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
            } }
self.form.append(multivaluedSection)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a custom selector row.

You just need to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#custom-presenter-rows), make a custom push row,

```
public final class CustomPushRow: SelectorRow<PushSelectorCell<SomeType>, YourSubFormVC>, RowType {

    public required init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        presentationMode = .show(controllerProvider: ControllerProvider.callback {
            return YourSubFormVC(){ _ in }
            }, onDismiss: { vc in
                _ = vc.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
    }
}
```

`YourSubFormVC` is the VC that is going to be presented when a suer taps on the row. It should conform to `TypedRowControllerType`. Since you want this VC to be a form as well, make it inherit from `FormViewController` and start building the form in `viewDidLoad`!